# How to reduce "dirtied buffers" occurence

Tags: postgresql

We have a table:

```
\d+ alarm_journals
      Table "public.alarm_journals"
     Column      |            Type
-----------------+-----------------------------
 id              | integer
 project_id      | integer
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone
 active          | boolean
Indexes:
    "alarm_journals_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_alarm_journals_common_active" btree (project_id, updated_at) WHERE active
```

There are many inserts into this table (1 million per day) and many updates of the 'active'-field from TRUE to FALSE.

Sometimes we have the lag for the query with `active = TRUE` (first log):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) SELECT "alarm_journals".* FROM "alarm_journals" WHERE (project_id = 280) AND ((active = TRUE  AND (updated_at <= '2017-07-27 03:47:06 UTC')))  ORDER BY "alarm_journals"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.41..7.59 rows=1 width=285) (actual time=0.044..32337.127 rows=20 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=18 read=1659 dirtied=1568 written=31
   ->  Index Scan Backward using index_alarm_journals_common_active on alarm_journals  (cost=0.41..7.59 rows=1 width=285) (actual time=0.044..32337.114 rows=20 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((project_id = 280) AND (updated_at <= '2017-07-27 03:47:06'::timestamp without time zone))
         Buffers: shared hit=18 read=1659 dirtied=1568 written=31
 Planning time: 506.406 ms
 Execution time: 32337.355 ms
(7 rows)
```

However it dissappears as soon as the similar query is executed (second log):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) SELECT "alarm_journals".* FROM "alarm_journals" WHERE (project_id = 280) AND ((active = TRUE  AND (updated_at <= '2017-07-27 03:47:06 UTC')))  ORDER BY "alarm_journals"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
                                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=0.41..7.59 rows=1 width=285) (actual time=166.317..401.424 rows=12 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=16
  ->  Index Scan Backward using index_alarm_journals_common_active on alarm_journals  (cost=0.41..7.59 rows=1 width=285) (actual time=166.315..401.413 rows=12 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((project_id = 280) AND (updated_at <= '2017-07-27 03:47:06'::timestamp without time zone))
        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=16
Planning time: 0.354 ms
Execution time: 402.204 ms
(7 rows)
```

We see many "dirtied buffers" in the first log (suppose that it causes the problem), but there is no any in the second log.
VACUUM-ing helps us to avoid this problem, but it takes 6 hours for execution.

How can we avoid queries which take a long time for execution (caused by "dirtied buffers")?

**Update:**

Vacuum command: `VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) alarm_journals;`

Comment: Did you disabled autovacuum ?
What vacuum command did you pass ?
Could you copy the exact logs you found ?
What are your "first" and "second" log ?

Comment: autovacuum is not disabled. I add vacuum command into question. I mark "first" and "second" log in question, I mean explain logs.

Comment: Could you add your postgreSQL log file (or an extract for when you had the issue) ?

Comment: What does the query that updates active from true to false look like?